# Navigating between VIM windows in an alternative way

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> to navigate between VIM split windows. Does there exist any different ways to do this?

For example, if I have, say, 5 split windows opened and want to navigate to the top left corner window, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> is very uncomfortable as it requires many keystrokes.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Why not setup something like these?

```
nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h
nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k
nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l
```

*Much quicker ...*

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of this solution but I was searching for something what would allow to navigate to a specific window. Anyways, this should be a satisfiable solution in case no alternatives exists.

Comment: @Adas - There is no better way, not that I'm aware of. The thing is, you don't navigate through windows (they're just ... viewpoints). You navigate through buffers. So if you have a 2x2 window configuration, the upper left will not necessarily be the 1st, upper right the second and so on ...

Comment: I have `nnoremap <cr> <c-w>w`, since I never use the return key in normal mode. Then it is effortless to cycle through the splits.

Comment: @PrinceGoulash - Except you have to hit it 3 times if you got 4 splits, and so on ... but okey

Comment: This is a little old, but for anyone who ends up here, it could be worth checking out [minibufexpl.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159).  Easily edit multiple files in "tabs"

Comment: Combine PrinceGoulash's mapping with skeept's answer and all you have to do is type `<number><cr>` to go to any split instantly

Answer (score 26):

You can use `<number><c-w>w` to switch to a particular window.
So `1<c-w>w` goes the the first window (top left corner)
`11<c-w>w` moves to the last window (here I assume you have less than 11 splits).

I also find the following mappings convenient and have them in my .vimrc

```
nnoremap <tab> <c-w>
nnoremap <tab><tab> <c-w><c-w>
```

which I use for window stitching
(for some reason if I don't define the second mapping 
if I hit tab twice I get a message "no identifier under the cursor)

Reading the help page for CTRL-W, there is even a more convenient way than
`1<c-w>w` and `11<c-w>w` to go to the first and last window:
`<c-w>t` goes to the top window and `<c-w>b` goes to the bottom window.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `nnoremap` command in your vimrc to use custom keybindings.

The syntax of `nnoremap` is this:

```
nnoremap new_keybinding keystrokes
```

The nnoremap command assigns a new keybinding that, when you press it in normal mode, the sequence of keystrokes that have been assigned to this command are echoed to Vim.

**EDIT**: There's also the `nmap` command. <strike>The difference between the two is that `nmap` allows to overwrite your current keybindings, while `nnoremap` does not.</strike> 
The difference between them is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3776182/676939).

For example, I have put these lines in my `.vimrc`:

```
"Better window navigation
nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k
nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h
nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l
```

This allows me to use <kbd>Ctrl+j</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+k</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+h</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+l</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> for window navigation, while retaining the old keybindings.

You can also look up `:help key-mappings` for more information.

Comment: Regarding nmap/nnoremap - no, that is not the difference. You can overwrite your nnoremap mappings just like any other, The difference is that nnoremap is not recursive.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3633/1841) on the SE site dedicated to Vim, I came up to another alternative which uses a plugin to create a submode dedicated to windows management. It means that with a combination of keys I enter a new mode in which some keys will allow me to do different actions on the windows.

After installing [vim-submode](https://github.com/kana/vim-submode) let's add some lines to our `vimrc` to configure a new mode:

```
" Create a submode to handle windows
" The submode is entered whith <Leader>k and exited with <Leader>
call submode#enter_with('WindowsMode', 'n', '', '<Leader>k', ':echo "windows mode"<CR>')
call submode#leave_with('WindowsMode', 'n', '', '<Leader>')
```

Now you simply have to press <kbd>Leader</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to enter the new mode *(You can change this with the line `submode#enter_with`)* and press <kbd>Leader</kbd> to exit it.

```
" Change of windows with hjkl
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', 'j', '<C-w>j')
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', 'k', '<C-w>k')
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', 'h', '<C-w>h')
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', 'l', '<C-w>l')
```

With these lines, after you entered the new mode *(with <kbd>Leader</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>)* you'll be able to move between your windows with the keys `hjkl` as if you were using `<c-w>hjlk` in normal mode.

```
" Resize windows with <C-yuio> (interesting on azerty keyboards)
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', 'u', '<C-w>-')
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', 'i', '<C-w>+')
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', 'y', '<C-w><')
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', 'o', '<C-w>>')
```

Some few more lines to allow the resizing of the window with `yuio` *(I choose these keys because on an azerty keyboard they are just on the row over `hjkl` and are pretty convenient to use, maybe it would be more useful to change that on a qwerty keyboard, Im not sure)*.

```
" Move windows with <C-hjkl>
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', '<C-j>', '<C-w>J')
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', '<C-k>', '<C-w>K')
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', '<C-h>', '<C-w>H')
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', '<C-l>', '<C-w>L')
```

Let's move the windows with `<C-hjkl>`.

```
" close a window with q
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', 'q', '<C-w>c')

" split windows with / and !
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', '/', '<C-w>s')
call submode#map('WindowsMode', 'n', '', '!', '<C-w>v')
```

And some more mappings to close a window and create new splits.

```
let g:submode_keep_leaving_key = 1
let g:submode_timeout = 0
```

Finally these options allow to keep a key pressed and it will repeat its action.

**Note** I am aware that this answer describe more than just navigating between windows as OP was asking. I think that creating a submode is pretty convenient but is only interest if the submode allows to do more than just one action.

Answer (score 0):

You can create diagonal movements by continuing `<C-w>` a second time in another direction.

```
  "move from bottom left to top right diagonally
  "Mnemonic: keyboard finger movement from j to i
  nnoremap <C-i> <C-w>l<C-w>k 

  "move from top right to bottom left diagonally
  "Mnemonic: keyboard finger movement from j to n
  nnoremap <C-n> <C-w>h<C-w>j 

  "move from  top left to bottom right diagonally
  "Mnemonic: keyboard finger movement from j to m
  nnoremap <C-m> <C-w>l<C-w>j

  "move from bottom right to top left diagonally
  "Mnemonic: keyboard finger movement from j to y
  nnoremap <C-y> <C-w>h<C-w>k
```

Comment: <c-m> (^M) has special meaning and could break in some situations