# Vim: Why does noremap not work in insert mode?

Tags: keyboard, vim

Consider the unbinding of the arrow keys using

```
 noremap <Left>  <NOP>
 noremap <Right> <NOP>
 noremap <Up>    <NOP>
 noremap <Down>  <NOP>
```

This works in normal mode, but it does *not* work in insert mode: one can still navigate with the arrow keys. As a countermeasure, one must include

```
 inoremap <Left>  <NOP>
 inoremap <Right> <NOP>
 inoremap <Up>    <NOP>
 inoremap <Down>  <NOP>
```

But this doesn't really make sense to me, since I assume `map` and `noremap` should work in all modes, while prepending `n/v/x/s/o/i/l/c` specifies the mapping to work only within that specific mode. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why there isn't an all-inclusive modal map, rather than issuing both map and map!

That's easy to explain: In insert mode mappings, Vim doesn't automatically switch to normal mode (you may want to stay in insert mode, though text translations are typically done via `:iabb`, not via `:imap`), so the set of applicable commands is totally different. For example, in normal mode Ctrl-U scrolls upwards, but in insert mode it deletes the entered characters in the line!

Prefixes like `<C-O>` temporarily switch from insert mode to normal mode. Actually, one often even has to define a different prefix for command line mode, too, as shown by this example:

```
noremap <C-Tab> :<C-U>tabnext<CR>
inoremap <C-Tab> <C-O>:tabnext<CR>
cnoremap <C-Tab> <C-C>:tabnext<CR>
```

So when defining mappings, always consider in which modes they are needed and whether they need remapping (`:nmap` vs. `:noremap`, prefer the latter).

Comment: It's not immediately clear that your blockquote “why there isn't an all-inclusive modal map, rather than issuing both map and map!” is quoting part of [nil's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953183#comment17559832_12953259) on Paul Ruane's answer.

Comment: So apparently I'm supposed to comment on this answer rather than fix it. The quote from nil's comment doesn't read properly, even though nil's original sentence is grammatically correct. `<C-O>` and `<C-C>` aren't prefices; they don't have to be at the start. `nmap` is not the recursive equivalent to `noremap`, so it could be improved by changing `nmap` to `map` or saying ‘`*map` vs. `*noremap`’. I fixed these problems in an edit, but it got rejected. I always seem to get told-off for either editing too little or editing too much; I can't win with the moderators. SE is too * bureaucratic.

Answer (score 4):

```
:help map-overview
```

map (and noremap) are for normal, visual, select and operator-pending modes.

Comment: Ah! Thank certainly makes sense. [I had based my question off the answer located here, but I'll edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776117/vim-what-is-the-difference-between-the-remap-noremap-nnoremap-and-vnoremap-ma) so no one else gets the wrong idea like I did. Is there a reason why there *isn't* an all-inclusive modal map, rather than issuing both `map` and `map!`?

Comment: @nil: The reason is probably that your example of disabling functionality is one of very few cases where the same mapping would have the same effect in all of the modes.

Comment: I read through from `map-overview` down to the end of the subsection, which was a little tough going, only to find that the next subsection, which is *1.4 LISTING MAPPINGS* (`:help map-listing`), actually provides a far better overview than `map-overview` does!

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what you might expect, `noremap` and `map` do not actually apply to all modes. Based on the very useful summary from `:help map-listing`, here is a list of the characters that can be prefixed (or suffixed in the case of `!`) to `map`, `noremap`, `unmap`, and `mapclear`, along with the modes that they apply to:

- (none) – Normal, Visual, Select, and Operator-pending
- `n` – Normal
- `v` – Visual and Select
- `x` – Visual
- `s` – Select
- `o` – Operator-pending
- `!` – Insert and Command-line
- `i` – Insert
- `c` – Command-line
- `l` – ":lmap" mappings for Insert, Command-line, and Lang-Arg

So a `noremap` mapping will have no effect in Insert or Command-line mode, and without consideration, may not work as intended in Visual, Select, or Operator-pending mode either.

However, mappings can be adapted to work in different modes, simply by changing mode and back in the mapping. For example, `noremap` mappings that issue command-line commands but only work in Normal mode can adapted to also work in the other modes as shown by this example:

```
noremap <C-Tab> :<C-U>set list!<CR>
inoremap <C-Tab> <C-O>:set list!<CR>
cnoremap <C-Tab> <C-C>:set list!<CR>:<Up>
```

`noremap` applies to the Normal, Visual, Select, and Operator-pending modes, for which `:<C-U>` enters Command-line mode then clears the current line in case Vim inserts a range; `inoremap` applies to Insert mode, for which `<C-O>:` temporarily exits to Normal mode then enters Command-line mode; and `cnoremap` applies to Command-line mode, for which `<C-C>:` exits and re-enters Command-line mode to clear the line but, unlike `<C-U>`, retain it in the command history so that `:<Up>` can bring it back.

These three mappings cover all six modes. (Apparently ‘Lang-Arg’ isn't a mode.) There are some corner-cases where it doesn't work, but then there are also some cases it works when I'd have thought it wouldn't, and I don't understand why. Also, most of the modes will loose little things like selections and pending operators, even if the mapped command wouldn't otherwise loose these things. For instance, when in Insert mode, I don't see why the example I've given would need to break the current edit into separate changes in the undo/redo history (try typing `i123<C-O><Esc>456<Esc>u`). To be honest using key mappings to run commands in this way seems like a bit of a hack to me, but I don't know another way.