# Remapping "Y" in vim

Tags: vim, key-bindings

The copy-paste functions in vim seem a bit inconsistent to me. The commands `yy`, `dd` and `cc` yank/delete the whole line. The commands `D` and `C` delete from the cursor to the end of line, but `Y` yanks the whole line instead. I want `Y` to work the same as `D` and `C`. So I put the following line in my `.vimrc`:

```
nmap Y y$
```

It doesn't seem to work though. My first idea was that it is because of some plugin interfering. I tried to put the command to both the beginning and the end of my `.vimrc`, but nothing helped. However, if I type the command manually (not from `.vimrc`), it works. Why is this? How do I make this work?

Comment: with that line at the end of your vimrc, what's the output of `:verbose map Y`?   btw, consider using `nnoremap Y y$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your vimrc is loaded before plugins are loaded, so this doesn't rule out that a plugin is overriding it.  Placing .vim files in `.vim/after/` will be loaded after plugins so you could test that theory that way if you want to avoid the route of removing your plugins one-by-one.

As mentioned by Kent, you should really consider using `nnoremap` over `nmap`.

Comment: Actually, the key was overwritten by the YankRing plugin. Mapping it from `.vim/after` worked, but I really need `nmap` instead of `nnoremap` because when I use `y` from within the command I want YankRing to actually catch it.

Comment: The YankRing docs mention that you can add the function:

function! YRRunAfterMaps()
    nnoremap Y   :<C-U>YRYankCount 'y$'<CR>
endfunction

to avoid YankRing taking precedence over the mapping.

Comment: Regarding @Kent's comment/suggestion: differences between `nmap`, `nnoremap`, and more are covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3776182/6411857).  You can also `:h nnoremap` to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

Pasting a new answer as code is not formatted in the comment of the answer above.

If the conflict is YankRing you can use:

```
function! YRRunAfterMaps()
    nnoremap Y   :<C-U>YRYankCount 'y$'<CR>
endfunction
nnoremap Y y$
```

source: [:help yankring-custom-maps](https://github.com/vim-scripts/YankRing.vim/blob/master/doc/yankring.txt#L519)