# How does command to put into shell argument at VI?

Tags: vim, vi

I am trying to put from current line of vi to shell argument.
I'd like to run at Virmc like this map  :! xpdf "xxxxxxxxxx"
I want to this. the xxxxxxxx will from current text line of vi.

Does anyone know how to put them into shell argument?

Currently tried :
.vimrc
map  :! xpdf :p^M
but it is not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
:nnoremap <F7> :execute(':!echo "' . getline(".") . '"')<CR>
```

This will [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776117/what-is-the-difference-between-the-remap-noremap-nnoremap-and-vnoremap-mapping) <kbd>F7</kbd> and will *echo* the content of the current line (getline(".")). You can just replace <kbd>F7</kbd> and *echo* for whatever you want.

A similar but most generic approach:

```
:nnoremap <F7> "zyiw:execute(':!echo "' . getreg('z') . '"')<CR>
```

Again will map <kbd>F7</kbd> but this time will *echo* the current word.

```
"z  => Just use z register, you can use any register you want (`:help registers`).
yiw => Copy the current word, you can replace for any yank command you like.
getreg('z') => Get the text copied in the register *z*.
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidEG. But I have still problem. I can't read the documents when I use your the first command. I used like this :nnoremap <F7> :execute(':!evince "' . getline(".") . '"')<CR> in the VI. Then the output message is like this. Unable to open document, file not open.

Comment: Either the line contains data that is not part of the file name or the content is not a full path that evince can find. For the first case I would go for the second command using `yiw`, you will need some tweak, `yiw` is not probably what you want to use. For the second case I would use something like `find` to locate the file: `:nnoremap <F7> :execute(':!find /path/to/your/pdf/files/ -name "' . getline(".") . '" -exec evince {} \;')<CR>`. Again probably will need tweaks.

Comment: Thanks @DavidEG , I'm not sure as to /path/to/your/pdf/files/. Did you mean that I have to type absolute path when I want see some pdf files? This is very uncomfortable way. Is there any way to fill with automatically?

Comment: I mean  /path/to/your/pdf/files/ this part should be assigned current vi path directory.

Comment: In that case you can use `getcwd()`. You might want to use something like https://github.com/vim-scripts/gf-ext (haven't used it but seems it does what you need)

Comment: Thanks, but I just want to use that. I don't need else.