# remapping $ doesn't apply to deleting with d$

Tags: vim

d$ works just fine.

I've remmapped $ to -

But d- now deletes to the beginning of the previous line.

My remap:

```
nnoremap - $
vnoremap - $
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use an operator pending mode mapping:

```
onoremap - $
```

I would also suggest you use `xnoremap - $` instead of `vnoremap` so that you avoid a mapping in selection mode.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that he can combine them into `noremap` (Assuming he doesn't need select)

Comment: Thanks so much! Found a full list too for anyone who's looking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776117/what-is-the-difference-between-the-remap-noremap-nnoremap-and-vnoremap-mapping/11676244#11676244