# Vimscript: one command is not calling the other

Tags: vim

I have the following code in my `vimrc` file:

```
" move line to end of file and add a timestamp
noremap ,d ddGp,t

" append a timestamp to the end of the line
nnoremap ,t A    <Esc>"=strftime("%H:%M")<CR>p
```

In the above code, `,t` works when called by itself. However, when called by `,d` the `,t` command does nothing. The rest of the `,d` command functions as expected. Why is this? How do I fix it?

Comment: What do you think the `noremap` command does? (Especially the nore prefix)

Comment: `:h map`, `:h noremap`. you will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`,d` is marked as `nore` which turns recursive mappings off, and thus fails to recognize `,t` as a command. Thank you [FDinoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1890567/fdinoff) for the answer.

More info:
[What is the difference between the remap, noremap, nnoremap and vnoremap mapping commands in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776117/what-is-the-difference-between-the-remap-noremap-nnoremap-and-vnoremap-mapping)