# What is the difference between the `noremap` and `nnoremap` command in vim?

Tags: vim

I'm editing my `vimrc` and I want to map some keys to `<F-1..12>`.

However I found some commands, like `noremap` and `nnoremap`. And they can work so good.

But I don't know what is the difference between the `noremap` and `nnoremap`.

I found [this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776117/what-is-the-difference-between-the-remap-noremap-nnoremap-and-vnoremap-mapping), but I still don't understand the difference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

nnoremap and noremap are both "no re(cursive) map", the difference is one with `n` the other not. that is `n  nore map` and `nore map`, in another word, you are asking the difference between `nmap` and `map`

The nnoremap/nmap will work only in Normal mode, but the noremap/map will work in Normal, Visual, Select and Operator-pending modes.

For more information, please read the help doc: `:h map-modes` There are two tables, which give nice overview of the relation between map commands and modes.

Comment: It's confusing to me too but the chart in `:h map-modes` is helpful (and entertaining `:nunmap can also be used outside of a monastery.`)