# Vim simple mapping

Tags: vim

I started using Vim recently, just installed NERDTree (a plugin to navigate files).
The command to access that plugin is `:NERDTree` so I though it's a good idea to start learning mappings by assigning one to that command.

So I added to my `.vimrc` file the following line: `map :nt :NERDTree` - but when I type `:nt` in a vim file (even after restarting) I receive the following error message: `not an editor command: nt`

I also tried to add the mapping directly while editing a file by typing `:map :nt :NERDTree` but it returned the same error when I tried to use the command.

I checked that answer:[What is the difference between the remap, noremap, nnoremap and vnoremap mapping commands in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776117/what-is-the-difference-between-the-remap-noremap-nnoremap-and-vnoremap-mapping), so it seems to me that `:map` (opposed to `noremap` etc.) is the good command for that.

The plugin works fine when typing the original command.

What am I doing wrong? (sorry for the noob question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `:NERDTree` is a command, not a mapping, so there's no reason for creating a recursive mapping, here.
- `:map` is too overreaching. You should use `:<mode>map` (for recursive mappings) or `:<mode>noremap` (for nn-recursive mappings).
- You are missing a `<CR>` at the end of your mapping to tell Vim to actually execute the `:NERDTree` command.

In this specific case, the right mapping would be:

```
nnoremap :tn :NERDTree<CR>
```

But mapping something to `:<anything>` is not a good idea because it will introduce a timeout whenever you try to execute an Ex command. This means that you need to find another combo. Why not `<Space>n`?

```
nnoremap <Space>n :NERDTree<CR>
```

Comment: excellent, thx a lot! Quick question what do you mean by "because it will introduce a timeout whenever you try to execute an Ex command" ?

Comment: `:` is the normal mode command that puts you in command-line mode. If you map something to `:` in normal mode, say `:tn`, Vim needs to decide what you actually want to do and uses a timeout for that. If you are a quick typist you probably won't notice it but if you are a normal human being you'll definitely notice it.

Answer (score 3):

With the mapping that you have, it will be require multiple keystroke. Will it be okay for you to use a single key like <kbd>F2</kbd>?

```
 nnoremap <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

This will toggle open/close `NERDTree` upon pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> and save you some key stroke.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1))
you can figure out, how vim's mapping work and look like ;). Don't forget to source your new .vimrc before using.

Comment: Ok thx. What do you mean by "Don't forget to source your new .vimrc before using" ?

Comment: He means that if you add a mapping to your .vimrc, you either need to restart vim or source your .vimrc before the mapping takes effect: `:source ~/.vimrc`

Comment: @jimbasquiat Great! If you think this answer is the right, please mark this answer as right or please upvote it. About your other question: every rc file, doesn't matter which one, needs to be sourced after updating. So, if you have had any changes in your `.vimrc` file, you need to source it. You have to type in your terminal, if your `pwd` is where your `.vimrc` exists: `source .vimrc` or the short form `. .vimrc`. Only than your update will be recognized by vim.