# How to make vim for running and compiling Java files as an IDE?

Tags: vim

I already use a vim function in Linux vimrc file to execute Java files by just pressing 'F5'.

Below is the function which I use.

```
inoremap <F5> <Esc> :call CompileRunGcc()<CR><CR>
func! CompileRunGcc()
exec "w"
if &filetype == 'java'
exec "!javac %"
exec "!time java -cp %:p:h %:t:r"
endif
endfunc
```

But when there is a compiling error, it shows the error message and also the output of the previous compiled program.

What I want is to be shown only the error message without the output of the previous compiled program. How can I do that?

Comment: I would *strongly* suggest (and I'm a vim fan, note) that you're *much* more productive using a Java IDE, such as the free Intellij Community edition (other free IDEs are, of course, available)

Comment: Thankz for the advise @BrianAgnew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, you'd better use the quickfix list feature to import the errors and warnings found into Vim. From there you'll be able to navigate the errors with `:cnext`, `:cprev`...

Regarding what's best with Java, you'll have to explore the various Java related *compiler* plugins. There is a `:compiler javac` for instance.

Regarding how to know whether the compilation has succeeded or not I use the method I've described in a similar Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56991040/15934

The only thing that changes is the way the `exec_line` variable would be built. It would look like (untested)

```
" From my build-tools-wrapper plugin
function! lh#btw#build#_get_metrics() abort
  let qf = getqflist()
  let recognized = filter(qf, 'get(v:val, "valid", 1)')
  " TODO: support other locales, see lh#po#context().tranlate()
  let errors   = filter(copy(recognized), 'v:val.type == "E" || v:val.text =~ "\\v^ *(error|erreur)"')
  let warnings = filter(copy(recognized), 'v:val.type == "W" || v:val.text =~ "\\v^ *(warning|attention)"')
  let res = { 'all': len(qf), 'errors': len(errors), 'warnings': len(warnings) }
  return res
endfunction


" in a java ftplugin    
function s:build_and_run(file) abort
  let tgt  = fnamemodify(a:file, ':r')
  " to make sure the buffer is saved
  exe 'update ' . a:file
  exe 'make ' . tgt
  if lh#btw#build#_get_metrics().errors
    echom "Error detected, execution aborted"
    copen
    return
  endif

  let path = fnamemodify(a:file, ':p:h')
  let exec_line = '!time java -cp ' . path. ' ' . tgt
  exe exec_line
endfunction

" With <buffer>, I assume this is defined in a java-ftplugin, because the 
" specific '!time java'. It could be generalized to many different 
" languages though.
nnoremap <buffer> µ :<C-U>call <sid>build_and_run(expand('%'))<cr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`v:shell_error`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#v%3Ashell_error) variable to check whether the `javac` command has failed. In that case, you can skip running the program, in which case the error messages will be left around for you to inspect.

```
function! CompileRunGcc()
  exec "w"
  if &filetype ==# 'java'
    exec "!javac %"
    if !v:shell_error
      exec "!time java -cp %:p:h %:t:r"
    endif
  endif
endfunction
```