# g++ fatal error no such file or directory

Tags: vim, g++

So I am using the [gvim editor](https://www.vim.org/download.php) to program in C++, however when I open a `.cpp` file on the editor then type `:!g++ -std=C++17 file.cpp -o file` I get this error:
See attached file below:

[image]

```sh
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c(g++ -std=c++17 file.cpp - o file)
g++: error: file.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated
```

Now is this related to vim, or to my command?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're unfortunately using gcc-mingw that doesn't come with gnumake properly configured (`:let $CXXFLAGS='-std=c++17 -Wall -Werror'`+ `make %<` would have been enough otherwise). Thus you'll have a do a few things manually. And don't misspell the parameters to g++. And forget `:!{compilername}`, this is want we had to do 25 years ago with vi. Unlike vi, vim permits to integrate compilation.

```
" to do once
:let &makeprg='g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Werror % -o %<'

" to execute each time to compile
:make
:copen

" to navigate the errors
:cc      " jump to error under cursor
:cnext   " jump to next error
:cprev   " jump to previous error
:cclose  " close the quickfix window
```

-> `:h quickfix`

This shouldn't execute g++ from the wrong directory. If this still does, run `:cd %:h`.

The execution should work with `:./%`.

And if you wish to have hot keys for that...

```
nnoremap <silent> <F7>   :<c-u>update<cr>:make<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <C-F5> :<c-u>./%<cr>

nnoremap <silent> <F3>   :<c-u>cnext<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <S-F3> :<c-u>cprev<cr>
```

Automatically opening the quickfix windows only if there are errors or executing the result only if there are no errors requires a [little more work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56991040/15934).

Comment: Thanks, however how do I run my program after "making it"?

Comment: And also how would I set a hotkey to do that?