# VIM map inner word function when i is move command

Tags: dictionary, vim, action, cpu-word, hotkeys

I am learning vim and slowly but surely adapting my vimrc.

I am moving around with "jlim" and entering insert mode with k.
All I want to do is combine actions with text-objects.

But when I want to change inner word (should be c k w) for me I go one line up instead of change the inner word. I have checked :index and :c and :iw but I dont understand how to map my actions to inner word??

vimrc:

```
`" set move keys in vim
   map m <down>
   map i <up>
   map j <left>
   map l <right>
`
```

greetings

SOLUTION to "{action} {text object}" while k is insert:

```
" set move keys in vim
nnoremap m <down>
nnoremap i <up>
nnoremap j <left>
nnoremap l <right>

" n for normal mode and noremap to not make k map to up
nnoremap k i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are looking for `:h onoremap` if you want ckw to do ciw you need

`:onoremap kw viw`

This would be necessary for all types of bracket (for i inner and a around movement (`ciw` and `caw`)). I would not recommend that. Just stick with the default.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have to remap all iw and ow commands in my vimrc now but it does what I want!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change all the things that `i` does to `k` (which I'd advise against, they are mnemonics for a reason), you can just `map` it.

That being said, bare `map` is overkill. You'll be better off with `noremap` which [won't recursively change your mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3776182/5889131). You'd also be better off specifying the mode you want these mappings to use. If you have to change the movement keys (which I also wouldn't recommend), I'd suggest

```
nnoremap m <down>
nnoremap j <left>
nnoremap l <right>
nnoremap i <up>
```

Then you can change what you want `k` to do with just another `nnoremap`:

```
"n for normal mode, noremap for not making your k map to <up>
nnoremap k i
```

Comment: Sadly I can't give upvotes yet but thank you for the explanation of map and noremap!

Comment: FWIW, I don't think the person whose answer you accepted is correct. I tested doing `nnoremap k i` and it appears to do all the `i`nner changes correctly. `ckw`, `ck(`, etc, "just work" with the one remap.