# vim nmap which disables another nmap

Tags: vim, keymapping

In my .vimrc I have these lines

```
nmap :s :update<cr>
nmap <F5> :set number!<cr>
```

Without the former mapping, the latter works, otherwise it doesn't. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the second mapping begins in a way, `:s` in `:set`, that triggers the previous mapping.

In general you should use non-recursive mappings, unless you have a reason to use recursive mappings.

In this case, you have to use

```
nnoremap :s :update<cr>
nnoremap <F5> :set number!<cr>
```

More info at

- [`:help recursive_mapping`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/map.txt#L750)
- [What is the difference between the remap, noremap, nnoremap and vnoremap mapping commands in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776117/what-is-the-difference-between-the-remap-noremap-nnoremap-and-vnoremap-mapping)
- [Recursive mappings - Vim Tips Wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Recursive_mappings)
- [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way - Chapter 5](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html)