# Vim: change mapping for command-line mode (:)

Tags: vim, mapping, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to change the shortcut for entering command-line mode in vim from `:` to `;`.

I can do:

```
:map ; :
```

and that works, but now I want to remap `:` to other command. If I do that `;` is changed too and I cannot enter command line mode any more.

I suppose I should use something like:

```
:map : <command-line-mode>
```

but I don't know the correct command to use.

Comment: Do you know the difference between `:map` and `:noremap`? http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:noremap

Comment: Use not recursive mapping `noremap` instead. See [What is the difference between the remap, noremap, nnoremap and vnoremap mapping commands in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776117/what-is-the-difference-between-the-remap-noremap-nnoremap-and-vnoremap-mapping)

Answer (score 1):

```
:noremap ; :
:noremap : <something else>
```

Using `map` only will map the key recursively, meaning if you map `;` to `:`, then `:` to someting else, now both `;` and `:` will do whatever you mapped `:` to do. Because `;` is mapped to do whatever `:` does. to prevent this recursive behavior, use non-recursive maps `noremap`, which will map each key independently of what the mapped-to key does.