# How to remap the following to "Control + Tilda" like in VS Code for opening a terminal?

Tags: vim

Given this code:

```
map <F6> :let $VIM_DIR=expand('%:p:h')<CR>:terminal<CR>cd $VIM_DIR<CR>
```

I can press F6 and vim automatically open a split with current directory in a terminal.

I would like to change this keymap to something like Control + ~.

What I tried:

```
map <c+~> :let $VIM_DIR=expand('%:p:h')<CR>:terminal<CR>cd $VIM_DIR<CR>
map <c+`> :let $VIM_DIR=expand('%:p:h')<CR>:terminal<CR>cd $VIM_DIR<CR>

map <C+~> :let $VIM_DIR=expand('%:p:h')<CR>:terminal<CR>cd $VIM_DIR<CR>
map <C+`> :let $VIM_DIR=expand('%:p:h')<CR>:terminal<CR>cd $VIM_DIR<CR>
```

with none working.

Comment: In Vim, `<C-a>` is not really "Control key + a", it actually is the ASCII control code `^A`. Since there is no `^~` control code in ASCII you can't really expect `<C-~>` to work.

Answer (score 0):

A good way of checking what the proper keyboard notation is for a given shortcut is to use `Ctrl-V` on the vim command line.  For example, in Windows GVIM with a UK keyboard, pressing `Ctrl-~` means pressing `Ctrl-Shift-#` ([as `~` is "above" the `#` on my keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards#/media/File:KB_United_Kingdom.svg)).  For some reason, if I press:

`: Ctrl-V Ctrl-Shift-#`

I get this:

[image]

Implying that Vim is interpreting `Ctrl-Shift-#` as `<C-S-^>`.  Therefore, if I want to make that do the same as `F6`, I could take advantage of [recursive mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776117/what-is-the-difference-between-the-remap-noremap-nnoremap-and-vnoremap-mapping/3776182#3776182) and type:

```
:nmap <C-S-^> <F6>
```

and it should work.  Note that if I'm typing this interactively on the command-line, I can type the `<C-S-^>` bit as `Ctrl-V Ctrl-Shift-#`.

Not all keyboard shortcuts will work this way as some may be grabbed by other processes (e.g. `Win-L` on Windows will lock the computer and I don't think you can override that in Vim).